# Polar double integral question

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates

[image]

Translating to polar I got a double integral with r=0 to 3 and theta = 0 to arccos(sqrt(0.9)/3) of

5rcos(theta)*rsin(theta)-rsin(theta)

And when I throw that in Wolfram alpha to evaluate I get ~14 which it says is wrong when I submit it

[image]

At this point I'm more concerned with understanding where I went wrong than with the right answer....any ideas?

Comment: Second angle you should obtain from $\tan \theta =3$.

Comment: I had a typo in the OP (which I've fixed) I originally had arccos(sqrt(9)/3) when it should have read arccos(sqrt(0.9)/3)

Comment: I wrote in the answer which curve turns into which one and which integral is obtained

Comment: Also you missed Jacobian for polar coordinates in integrand.

Comment: arccos(sqrt(0.9)/3) and arctan(3) are the same, so at least I got the bounds correct.  I added the screenshot from Wolfram Alpha...I've been staring at this so long I'm afraid I'm making a very silly mistake

Comment: One more: on your image $5$ is outside of brackets, while by OP it is inside.

Comment: Frustrating...I was goofing the entry on Wolfram Alpha...at least I had the work right.  Thanks1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using polar coordinates $x = r\cos \theta, y = r \sin \theta$ we have, that circle $x^2+y^2=9$ goes to $r=3$. $y=0$ gives $\theta = 0$ and $y=3x$ gives $\theta =\arctan 3$, so for integral in first quadrant we have
$$\int\limits_{0}^{\arctan 3}\int\limits_{0}^{3}r\cdot(5r^2\sin \theta \cos \theta-r \sin \theta)drd\theta$$

Addition
[image]